# How can I make Robot type a `:`?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I want to type `:` using Java Robot. However, I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException`. My code is:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code.].
```

I also tried with:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try with this code :

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

As with the keyboard you enter : when you press shift + ;. the same you need to simulate.

Try running this code just to try out which works fine with above answer:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot robot;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);  
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);  
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);  
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch bloc
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The result is the same:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
 at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
 at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)

Comment: The problem is the semicolon keyEvent. If I execute this code, I get the same Exception but the shift key is "still pressed" after terminating it. Does this code work for you?

Comment: @Eric on my Windows XP box the above code works fine. If you are still getting an error I would try to just do a `keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON)` without the `VK_SHIFT` modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Java `Robot` class relies on a platform specific implementation of an undocumented interface called `java.awt.peer.RobotPeer`. The platform specific implementation decides what key press events are legal or illegal.

On my windows XP box, this works fine:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    } catch (final AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch bloc
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On a different platform you may want to try:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
    } catch (final AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch bloc
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code ;), maybe it helps (using ascii code alt+5+8=:):

```
robot9.delay(20);
robot9.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot9.delay(20);
robot9.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5);
robot9.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5);
robot9.delay(20);
robot9.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8);
robot9.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8);
robot9.delay(20);
robot9.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot9.delay(20);
```

Comment: Thank you. The concept works with : and also \ signs. So I can type file location to a pop-up file browser. You saved me some hours. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

This also seems to be language dependent. On a German keyboard, using the combination of `VK_SHIFT` and  `VK_PERIOD` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Java Robots, but if you're using shift, shouldn't you then type semicolon, because shift + semicolon = colon. So it's probably an illegal argument because colon isn't a key, semicolon is.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

---

```
        case KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON:
            if((event.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)!=0)
               System.out.println(":");
            else
                System.out.print(";");
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone build a KeyboardKeys class and published it here in SO.  it´s at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20979488/7069565.  In a nutshell, he types every character as an Alt + Number combination.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is an "upercase leter", that is, you only get it with the combination of Keys

> Shift+Coma

Try this:

```java
robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
//Since you have the Shift pressed it will generate a semi colon.
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)