# How to  upload file (with raduploader) using selenium RC?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-rc, radupload

I am trying to upload a file using `selenium`. but the problem is my upload field is not like

```
<input type="file".....> [where i can directly say "selenium.type("xpath ","file path") ]
```

but here, for uploading file we are using a Rad Uploader, and it is not recording anything in selenium IDE even though i click on `uploader`.

Does anybody know how to **upload file** with **Raduploader** using `Selenium`?

```
<object height="22px" type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainTabContainer_thirdTab_ChildPlaceHolderCa‌​mpVolunteers_fileUploadVolunteersilverlight04"
class="ruObject" style="width: 100%;">
```

this is some part of the code of **upload field**

Thanks.

Comment: When you are posting question on stack-overflow, It should be proper formatted and all important keywords should be highlighted.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing and particularly the last line.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Since [Rad Uploader](http://www.radinks.com/upload/) is basically a Java Applet, you could use [LiveConnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect) to interact with it!</del>

<del>There is even a tool for it and Selenium (though I'm not using it, so I can't tell whether it works well or not): http://fest.codehaus.org/Selenium</del>

If it doesn't work, then you'll probably need to use a different automation library to upload the files, because Selenium is not built to work neither with Java applet, nor outside the browser. Possible solutions include drag'n'dropping or (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>ing) the files from outside the window to your Uploader, or clicking blindly on the Browse button...

---

### Edit

I was obviously looking at the wrong product, because OP's code shows it's actually a Silverlight element, not a Java applet.

But - knowing that there's a tool for this for Java applets, I digged and found these:

[There is a tool for using Selenium RC with Silverlight!](http://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/) No idea how well it actually works, but you could give it a try. Yes, I know it's only Selenium RC, but you could try it with [`WebDriverBackedSelenium`](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#webdriver-backed-selenium-rc)...

Scott Hanselman's blog (very readable!) - "abusing" that Silverlight can run `Scriptable` methods. It is written for Selenium IDE, but the same will work for `WebDriver`, too.

[A testing framework for Silverlight.](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) By Microsoft. Selenium is for webpages, try this for some Silverlight magic.

---

**EDIT 2:**

There's always the option I mentioned earlier. Since the upload thing is no `input`, but a Silverlight object and there's no API for WebDriver that would allow you to work with browser dialogs (or Silverlight objects), you can try this:

After you click the Silverlight element, there'll be a window popping up that you'll have no control over. In the browsers and operating systems I know, you can pretty much assume that after the window has been opened, the cursor is in the `File name` input. Please, make sure this assumption is true in your case, too.

If not, you could try to jump to it by pressing <kbd>Alt + N</kbd>, at least on Windows...

*(Java code follows! I really don't know C#. It works in Java, though. C#'s class that is similar to Java's `Robot` is [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx))*

If yes, you can "blindly" type the path into it using the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. In your case, that would be something in the way of:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("SWFUpload_0")).click();
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);        // C
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);    // : (colon)
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);    // / (slash)
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
// etc. for the whole file path

r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);    // confirm by pressing Enter in the end
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

It sucks, but it should work. Note that you might need these: [How can I make Robot type a `:`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736129/how-can-i-make-robot-type-a) and [Convert String to KeyEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248510/convert-string-to-keyevents)

Comment: Actually the link which you gave is based on java. But i am working with c#.

Comment: i used firebug and found the **html** code of **upload field**. it is like this, 
`<object id="some name" ......>` i tried `selenium.type` command but it's not working.

Comment: `<object height="22px" type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainTabContainer_thirdTab_ChildPlaceHolderCampVolunteers_fileUploadVolunteersilverlight04" class="ruObject" style="width: 100%;">`  this is some part of the code of **upload field**.

Comment: Okay, so it's a Silverlight object, not a Java applet (Huh, so there are more Rad Uploaders out there. I was looking at [this one](http://www.radinks.com/upload/) which is a Java applet.) The question gets edited.

Comment: i din't find any useful information. i have downloaded silverenium(silverlight+selenium) from the above link. but am unable to do anything with it.

Comment: Edited with the "blind typing" solution that works e.g. for Flash upload when done in Java. You'll need to do some research on the SendKeys class, though.