# Dealing with OS pop up windows in Selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a question regarding how to deal with an OS specific pop up window (in this case Windows) and if it is possible to access the elements in them for things such as photo uploads, document uploads, etc. So say if I have an "Add Photo" button and I click it, it will then lead me to a window like this..

[image]

So I am wondering if there is a way i can just do element.sendKeys(absolute path url) for the File Name.. Has anyone had success with something like this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle windows file upload using selenium webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are able to sendKeys() to the actual button for example:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(by.id("buttonId"));
button.sendKeys(pathToFile);
```

Comment: To the "Add Photos" button? so if I had WebElement addPhotos = By.xpath("blah...") I could do addPhotos.click() and addPhotos.sendKeys("path")? I dont see how that can work :/

Comment: Or are you saying just leave out the .click() entirely

Comment: Leave out the `.click()`. You can sendKeys directly to the `<input>` element