# Selenium webdriver JS doesn't click buttons after page has changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriverjs

I am testing my web application. I search for upload button and select file. Uploading changes URL of the page:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('upload')).click();
var upload = driver.findElement(By.id('files'));
var testDocAbsPath = getTestDocAbsPath('1run.docx');
upload.sendKeys(testDocAbsPath);
```

After this action I can't click buttons any more:

For example this one doesn't have any effect:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('btnId')).click();
```

while such button really presents on the new page. Probably some cache is not updated. How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you try to click the buttons? Does it throw any error?

Comment: after first line of your code, any file upload window open? how d you handle it?

Comment: similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha nothing happens during second click. Mahsum, your link doesn't address my question

Comment: Have you tried putting a sleep of say 5 or 10 seconds after `upload.sendKeys(testDocAbsPath);` to make sure that the upload is complete and js has been fully executed?

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha, there is no way to put sleep in js async driver.