# Selenium Webdriver, Uploadify how to upload file using Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

Uploadify, not exist a input element, so cannot use sendKeys upload.

I have found how to upload a file using Java: ([How to handle windows file upload using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver))

I want to know how upload file using Node.js?