# Selenium python interact with FileOpen window

Tags: python, selenium

From Selenium, I managed to automate my tasks for a website.
However I ran into a problem:I need to upload a file to my web-page before submitting the form.
It is NOT an option to write the uploaded file into it's input element, because it is more complicated than this.
So basically I need to launch the FileUpload dialog by clicking a button, sendKeys there, and then close it by clicking on Ok.
I am wondering if this is even possible using just Selenium?
I am using it from python (so I don't have access to Robot class)

> I tried so far:

```
element.click()
time.sleep(5)
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keys("path.to.myfile.txt")
alert.accept()
```

*(nothing happens - I mean, the file open dialog works fine, but it does not send the keys )*

> I also tried:

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
buildu = ActionChains(driver).send_keys('path.to.my.file.txt')
buildu.perform()
```

*(also not working)*

Maybe I am looking at it wrong...
Maybe the alerts is not a good approach?
Do you have any idea?
I would prefere not having to use AUTOIT (for my own reasons)

So my goal is to click on a link element (DONE) then the link opens the File Upload open file dialog (DONE), then I need to be able to enter a text in the only textBox of the new window, and click on the Ok button

**EDIT**
This is the Open File dialog that shows up.

[image]

All I want to do is send the filename directly to the window (the textBox is focused when the dialog shows up, so no need to make more actions). After I send the keys (text) I need to be able to click on the *Open* button

Comment: Hi, can you upload a screenshot of the dialog?

Comment: Sure, just a second...

Comment: Please have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: You can not use just `Selenium` for this purpose as file upload prompt window is not a web element. And you also can not sent text just to new window- you should `find` input field first

Comment: you'd better try to use Python `requests` module and send file within http POST request

Comment: @Andersson... I thought about that (from the very begining) but the post that the page sends, contains besides the regular inputs, 2 dynamic, session like, IDs, that I cannot generate. So this approach wont work. That is why I want to automate it with selenium

Comment: There are preferences that allow to download files with `Firefox Profile` avoiding prompt window. Maybe there are some preferences that allow to upload files also...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is restricted to windows 10 or works slightly different in other Windows versions but you can use the following code/idea.

1. Open the windows shell with `win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")`
2. **Send Tab keys to navigate through the open file dialog**
3. **Paste your absolute file path into the top of the dialog** and also into the file selection text field and send enter key when
   tab-navigating to the "open" button
4. **Make a sleep of at least 1 second between each action**.. otherwise Windows blocks this action.

   ```
   import win32com.client as comclt
   ```

   ...

   ```
       def handle_upload_file_dialog(self, file_path):
           sleep = 1
           windowsShell = comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
           time.sleep(sleep)
           windowsShell.SendKeys("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
           time.sleep(sleep)
           windowsShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
           time.sleep(sleep)
           windowsShell.SendKeys(file_path)
           time.sleep(sleep)
           windowsShell.SendKeys("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
           time.sleep(sleep)
           windowsShell.SendKeys(file_path)
           time.sleep(sleep)
           windowsShell.SendKeys("{TAB}{TAB}")
           time.sleep(sleep)
           windowsShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
   ```

   ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Java program that will paste the filename and press the enter key. I had this same problem exactly. This is how I implemented:

```
package myaots_basic;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class trial {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    StringSelection attach1 = new StringSelection ("C:\\My Office Documents\\Selinium projects\\Data\\attachment1.doc");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(attach1, null);
    Robot rb1 = new Robot();
    rb1.delay(3000);
    rb1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rb1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    rb1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    rb1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rb1.delay(500);
    rb1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);    // press Enter
    rb1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}

}
```

Name it to trial.jar. Make this class a an executable.

Then in your python code just add a simple step:
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call("java -jar trial.jar", shell=True)