# How to handle a file upload button using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access the file upload element from a webpage and handle it to upload a file and click on submit for processing. Please tell me how to handle the file upload dialog boxes? Also when using the code, it got struck-ed in the find element module itself. What can i do for that?

Comment: You can have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver
Hope this helps

Comment: There are n number of possible solutions over the internet. Have you tried anything ? if your question or issue is different than others then post your UI/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("SWFUpload_0")).click();
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);        // C
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);    // : (colon)
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);    // / (slash)
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
// etc. for the whole file path

r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);    // confirm by pressing Enter in the end
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: The most weird option :) why not just to sent the path strint to `<input type="file" id="SWFUpload_0">...</input>` element with `driver.findElement(By.id("SWFUpload_0")).sendKeys(pathToFile);`?