# How to upload file with Python + Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have `span` link to upload images. When i click this link it opens a Chrome Window to select a file. But Selenium can't do this automatically. How can I  handle this window and choose a file?

```
choose_photo = driver.find_element_by_id("form-2033-innerCt")
choose_photo.click()
choose_photo.send_keys("C:\\Users\\Support\\AppData\\Roaming\\Skype\\My Skype Received Files\\1.png")
```

And this is the HTML element to click

```
<span id="fileuploadfield-2034-button-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small">Choose photo</span>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Note that the `HTM`L element is not `type = file`, as you can see.

Comment: Can you check siblings/ancestors for `<input type="file">`?

Answer (score 2):

In HTML the common way to upload a file is to use an `input type=file`. I am guessing that in your case the `file` input is hidden and clicking the `span` triggers it. 
You can try to locate the hidden input and type into it.

See also [How to handle windows file upload using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

>

```
driver.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

>

OR 
Try to upload file using AutoIT, If this one does not work for you then use AutoIT for upload file

Comment: As i say before, there are not element with InputTypeFile. I will try your code

Comment: @Sergeymoroz Use AutoIT

Comment: choose_photo = driver.find_element_by_id("form-2033-innerCt")
choose_photo.click()

autoit.win_wait_active("Open")
print(autoit.win_get_title_by_handle())
autoit.send_keys(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Support\\AppData\\Roaming\\Skype\\", "1.png"))
autoit.send("{ENTER}")

Its also not working

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to download and install AutoIt :-**

1. Download link = http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/
2. Install
3. Go to your program menu and look at the AutoIt folder and open according to your system
4. Now download AutoIt script editor and install, download link = http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

**Steps to use AutoIT :-**

1. Identify the Windows control
2. Build an AutoIt script using identified windows control
3. Compile the .au3 script and convert it into .exe file
4. Call the .exe file into the Selenium test case

**Below is AutoIt Script :-**

Wait 10 seconds for the Upload window to appear

```
WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]","",10)
```

Set input focus to the edit control of Upload window using the handle returned by WinWait

```
 ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")

 Sleep(2000)
```

Set the File name text on the Edit field

```
  ControlSetText("File Upload", "", "Edit1", "SomeFile.txt")

  Sleep(2000)
```

Click on the Open button

```
ControlClick("File Upload", "","Button1");
```

5. Compile the `.au3 script` and convert it into `.exe` file
6. Call the `.exe` file into the Selenium test case e.g.

   ```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\AutoIt\AutoItTest.exe");
   ```