# Selecting a file from a windows dialog box in Telerik Web Test

Tags: web-testing, telerik-test-studio

[image]

Hi guys,

Is it possible to select a file from a dialog box when we are running a web test in Telerik Test Studio? The scenario of this execution is when we click a field in a web browser, a windows dialog box pops out and we would need to input a path to a local folder and select a file(SelectFile.PNG).

But I'm unable to detect any element from this dialog box presuming this is because the test script is a web test and hence this limitation(do correct me if i'm wrong).

Is there any workaround or suggestion to this limitation?

Many many thanks!

Best Regards,

Pravin

praja@dongenergy.dk

Comment: [Selenium equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a late response but if your recording is enabled, it should automatically record the step for a File Upload dialog box (and handle it appropriately when using play back).

Alternatively, you can manually add the "Dialogs->FileUpload" step, and fill in the properties appropriately.