# FileUpload with selenium and ExtJS

Tags: selenium, extjs

I am trying to test an Extjs 4 application that has a file upload. The test is written in selenium. The component is a Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField. And it works fine when the user clicks the browse button and selects the file.
However when this is done by selenium using sendkeys, or even when you paste the value in the field, then the upload no longer works.
I noticed that on server side the content length is no longer properly received.
Any fixes, workarounds for this problems?

Comment: why don't you use the selenium click function?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Click on what? If i click the browse button it opens the os file browser. what next?

Comment: oh now I understand your problem, but check this answer (especially the robot thingy) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver