# Automating Uploading File using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate uploading a file using selenium webdriver in Python. Right now, I have the following code:

```
url = "https://uploadfiles.io/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/path/to/firefoxdriver")
driver.get(url)
getForm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='dropzone needsclick dz-clickable']")
getForm.send_keys("/path/to/somefile")
```

However, this doesn't work. For some weird reason it tries to find the text I'm sending in to send_keys on the page (like when you do command+f).

Comment: Share the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

you must recheck X-PATH selector, now the class has been changed to [ufzone needsclick dz-clickable]. choose the right selector , you will get

Answer (score -1):

As explained here: [Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11258286/7744348), this form is not an input, so you might need to go about it differently.
The robot thing should work, provided that the field for typing is focused when opened.