# Selenium handling the opened file dialog with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to browser automation and learning selenium. I have managed to set up jar dependencies and the driver dependency too. It is opening the webpage.., detecting the loading of the page and also detecting element is available to click. But it has opened a `select file dialog box` and i am unable to select file via selenium.

Here is my java code :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://xyz.abc.pqr");

try 
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("element_id_1")));

    System.out.println("Loaded and in....");

    WebElement AttachMenu = driver.findElement(By.className("Class_1"));
    AttachMenu.click();
    System.out.println("Clicked Attach menu....");

    // <input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple="" style="display: none;">

    // As you can see above input element is not having any id or class

    // How do i sendkeys to above input element that has opened dialog

    // this is the question...

}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    System.out.println("Element not found...");
}

// driver.quit();
```

IT IS NOT UPLOAD IT IS JUST SELECTION OF FILE; I WILL CLICK ON UPLOAD BUTTON THEREAFTER...

Any help / inputs will be appreciated and thank you in advance for giving your valuable time over this question.

Comment: U can paste this code befor dialog box `driver.switch_to_active_element()`and `driver.find_element_by_I'd(I'd of dailog close button).click()`

Comment: @bhupathituraga, And how to load that dialog box with the absolute file path? Also will you please answer this question with some more details, so that it will be more clear to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle windows file upload using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @JeffC, Please make habit of reading the question before down-voting, It is related to Apple Mac OSX and not for the WINDOWS..!!

Comment: If you click the upload button, you have to deal with the dialog. Follow the instructions in the link.

Comment: @JeffC, Okay..., I am gonna follow the instructions and will update here.. Thank you

Comment: @JeffC, I am not able to click on <div role="button" title="attach"> this button as it has no class nor the id...!!

Comment: Keep the HTML snippet of that dialog box

Comment: @bhupathituraga, <input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple="" style="display: none;"> this is the HTML that opening file select dialog..  and dialog boxes do not have html codes it is populated by system

Comment: If you read the info in the link, you aren't supposed to click the button. Read it carefully and try the code there.

Comment: @JeffC, yes your link also helped me a lot. thanks it has been resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues :

1. How to click `<div role="button" title="Attach">` button; which has no class and no id
2. How to `sendkeys` to `<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple="" style="display: none;">` which also has no class and no id.

It has been solved after a lots of try and errors as ...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Attach']")).click();
System.out.println("Attach clicked....");

WebElement MediaButton = driver.findElement(By.className("xyzmm"));
MediaButton.click();

System.out.println("Select clicked....");
WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@accept='image/*,video/*']"));

uploadElement.sendKeys("/Users/Apple/Desktop/logos/Team1.png");
```

Still `uploadElement` dialog is visible.. and how to execute javascript to make it `display none` is in question..., trying on it now... The question has been resolved

Comment: can u give url for better understanding

Comment: web.whatsapp ... Actually i am going to do it for myself.. not for the illegal usages and distribution...

Comment: ok but xpath is wrong try by name findElement by name('file')

Comment: You should answer it with details and code so that it would be better to understand and i can also accept the answer