# Can I upload a file using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, ui-automation

I tried to automate a website using selenium with java.
But in the website there is a field for uploading pdf file from the system.
How can I upload a file in selenium ??
Here I attach a screenshot of that field [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne7As.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle windows file upload using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please share HTML of "choose file" button.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code , and don't change the focus of the browser by moving the cursor or pressing any keys .

```
public void navigateToWebSiteAndUploadFile() throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException, InterruptedException, AWTException {

     // Create a file object 
    File f = new File("resources\\DemoUpload.txt"); 
    // Get the absolute path of file f 
    String absoluteFilePath = f.getAbsolutePath();  
    //Copy the file path to clipboard
    StringSelection  autoCopiedFilePath = new StringSelection(absoluteFilePath);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(autoCopiedFilePath, null); 

    //Navigate to the URL
    driver.get("https://codepen.io/rcass/pen/MmYwEp");
    driver.switchTo().frame("result"); //switching the frame by name
    //Click on a button which opens the popup 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fileToUpload']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //This will paste the file path and name in the file explorer by pressing Ctrl +V combination.
    Robot  robot = new Robot(); 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);  
    // Pause should be used here to perform the action properly and release the  Ctrl +V keys
    Thread.sleep(2000); 
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);  
    Thread.sleep(8000);
    //press enter key after giving the file path.   
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Video link-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtqrVeN1Mk&t=19s

Comment: sorry it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. This concept enable a `input` field by Javascript and use it to upload file. You have to provide `choose file` button locator as `webelement` and `filePath` where file exist in your system.

```
 public void uploadFile(WebElement fileElement, String filePath) {
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        String activateField = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible'; arguments[0].style.display='block';";

        executor.executeScript(activateField, fileElement);
        executor.executeScript(activateField, fileElement.findElement(By.tagName("input")));
        fileElement.findElement(By.tagName("input")).sendKeys(filePath);
    }
```

`getDriver()` can be replaced by the way you are using `driver`instance. I am using it with `getDriver()` function.

Hope it will help you.