# Upload images from folder with selenium for .net

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, browser-automation

I am trying to automate upload images on this service:  https://kraken.io/web-interface, building console .net app and using selenium browser in background, so i am coming to this windows dialog, i need to insert in the path section programmatically , so to navigate to folder, and select only images.

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks,
Here is my code till now

https://github.com/kristijan-apostolov/imageOptimizer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle windows file upload using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: i tried to send keys, not to open the dialog like these example, but got error: "not intractable"


"In case of the Zamzar web, it should work perfectly. You don't click the element. You just type the path into it. To be concrete, this should be absolutely ok:

driver.findElement(By.id("inputFile")).sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");"

Comment: Can you try the second or third answer on the post? The third one is specifically in C#. Btw, you have a private repository - it is not possible for anyone to access your code. It's better if you post your code along with what you've tried until now.

Comment: Sor, now the repo is public