# Open File after navigating through website using Selenium

Tags: python, database, selenium, openfiledialog

I'm at the final stage of this small project using Python/Selenium to navigate through a platform I use to bulk upload csv files. [image]

I can't seem to find a way to specify the path/file location to then select (open) the file to upload to the website. I am trying to use the code below:

```
filepath = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="C:\\Users\\MyFolder")
subprocess.Popen('explorer "C:\my_file.csv"')
```

How do I select the correct file to then click 'open' after navigating through the website? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work around to this issue. I used the below code to locate the input element instead:

```
s = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
#file path specified with send_keys
s.send_keys(r"C:\Users\MyFolder\my_file.csv")
```

Here are some resources I used:
[Selenium Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

[Upload Files With Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-upload-file-with-selenium-python)

[Handle Windows File Upload Using Selenium - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256732/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver)

Thanks to anyone who wanted to help!