# Handle windows file upload using Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to upload the picture so that I can access it in my project, I have used the `sendKeys("path of the picture")` but by using it no action is performed,
please guide me, how to use the window pop up to upload the picture or give some idea, how can I upload the picture:

```
WebElement Account_logo = adriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='step1']/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div[12]/div[1]/div/div/span/div[2]/div[2]"));  
Account_logo.click();
Account_logo.sendKeys("C:/Users/romit/Desktop/LOGO.jpg");
```

Comment: on which browser you are testing this scenario ? Have you tried autoIT or robot class ?

Comment: AFAIK, a `<div>` tag won't accept a _filename_. Perhaps you have to use the file picker.

Comment: Share your HTML.

Comment: comment the 2nd line and run it.

Comment: I am testing it on the chrome browser, I have tried the robot and still not upload the picture @cruisepandey

Answer (score 0):

When setting the file path in your Java IDE, use the proper escape character for the back-slash.

```
Account_logo.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\romit\\Desktop\\LOGO.jpg");
```

Hope it helps !

If you want to upload a file, without having 'input' element, please refer [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025308/how-to-upload-file-photo-using-upload-image-button-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Could you please tell more about your uploading mechanism. do you have file input put field and submit button ?