# File Upload in Selenium not working with

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried uploading file to selenium using javascriptexecuter but it throwed an error like "This is insecure"

this is the tag i worked upon

{input type="file" name="fileUploader" id="fileUploader-fu" tabindex="-1" size="1"}

{input type="hidden" name="*charset*"}

{input type="hidden" id="fileUploader-fu_data" name="fileUploader-data" value=""}

and i used

try
        {

```
        WebElement elem=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='fileUploader']"));
        driver.
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", elem, "./payloads/SalesOrderSummary.xsd");
    System.out.println("here2");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

it gave me error like This is insecure

are there any alternatives to upload or any solution.

Thanks

Comment: you can simply pass file path using sendkeys instead of this javascript executor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Upload files using Selenium webdriver in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Comment: Please format your code and HTML properly. HTML tags don't use {}.

Comment: Absolute path is not an inssue, the Uploader is hidden division.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload the files using sendkeys too
sendkeys is not only send string to textboxs while it sets the value in your DOM too

So try this out

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='fileUploader']")).sendKeys(GIVE ABSOLUE PATH OF YOUR FILE);
```

Click on upload button too after this :)

get back to me if still facing problem :)

Comment: The Absolute path will not work as the Uploader is Hidden division.

Comment: Not really useful, since it will not work for most websites, as it only interacts with HTML5 based multiple file uploader.