# How to upload file using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, upload

Tried lot of suggestions available on stackoverflow regarding upload file using selenium webdriver, but issue still exists.

User clicks on Browse button, then a new popup window is displayed and then script will try to upload the file. My code below:

```
cd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='import_file']")).sendKeys("E://iMedicor - Karthik/2.Demographics/Patients_Data/Patient_One.xml");
```

[image]

If I clicked on Browse button following popup is displayed.
[image]

File is inside E drive. Tried script like below as well, but issue is still same.

```
cd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='import_file']")).click();
cd.switchTo().activeElement()
  .sendKeys("E://iMedicor - Karthik/2.Demographics/Patients_Data/Patient_One.xml");
```

Comment: [Here is another similar question. I hope this will help you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java

Comment: I have tried solutions mentioned in that one also. But it doesn't helps me. I have two file upload fields in same page..

Comment: Have you tried using autoIT script? It is one of the solution mentioned in abve link. AutoIT is of great help to handle Windows(only) native dialogs.

Comment: Hi, I have tried following code.. It works for me. But problem is File Upload window is not getting closed, even the file is uploaded... `cd.findElement(By.id("import_file")).click();
  cd.switchTo().activeElement()
            .sendKeys("E:\\iMedicor-Karthik\\2.Demographics\\Patients_Data\\Patient_One.xml");
  cd.findElement(By.id("btn_submit")).click();`

Comment: The problem is fixed now... I have used below code `cd.findElement(By.id("import_file")).sendKeys("E:\\iMedicor-Karthik\\2.Demographics\\Patients_Data\\Patient_One.xml");`. Actually the filepath caused a issue for me.. I have used `E:\\iMedicor-Karthik\\2.Demographics\\Patients_Data\\Patient_One.xml` instead of `E://iMedicor-Karthik/2.Demographics/Patients_Data/Patient_One.xml`

Comment: Please post code in your question so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: If you found the solution to your own problem, please post it as an answer and accept it so that question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved the issue..

`cd.findElement(By.id("import_file")).sendKeys("E:\\iMedicor-Karthik\\2.Demographi‌​cs\\Patients_Data\\Patient_One.xml");`

Actually the filepath caused a issue for me.. I have used

`E:\\iMedicor-Karthik\\2.Demographics\\Patients_Data\\Patient_One.xml`

instead of `E://iMedicor-Karthik/2.Demographics/Patients_Data/Patient_One.xml`