# Selecting a file when prompt appears to upload a file using Selenium-Webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automatically select a file into an upload prompt.
Here is the code for the upload section of the website.

```html
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="rAyNscZYeYLEYTV1rodwr0lQr_0Eadpfd11lcuHUvJf83lM57R2vruocFLDPjK0axYr_XBYgqmgTXVH_V2qHGFpAq-zGx_mMm72XIUj4Z6HlUjcyz47Vepfjysur7CR0N8xgHMkjW1KRgb4K6w6VPQ2" type="hidden">
<li>
  <input id="imageUpload" class="hideupload" name="imageUpload" multiple="" type="file">
  <a id="imageUploadLink" href="#"><i class="addContent_icon uploadlink"><img src="/Content/images/addContent-icon-images.png"></i>Upload Images</a>
</li>
```

The element of interest as far as I can tell is id: imageUploadLink. Clicking that will open the prompt to select file. Here is my code.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
sign_in(browser, myUsername, myPassword) #signs into testing site
browser.find_element(:id, 'imageUploadLink').click
element = browser.find_element(:id, 'imageUploadLink')
element.send_keys "/Users/DanielScarlett/Desktop/Example.JPG"
```

send_keys seems to be typed into the bottom of the browser in a sort of find section that disappears quickly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6QWr.jpg

I have tried many different ways to implement this, and nothing seems to work. Also, couldn't find anything anywhere to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to select file via browse and then click on `Upload Images` link. If that is the case, ID for your interest is `imageUpload`.
Code is in Java, you can change for ruby.

It worked for me using :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("imageUpload")).sendKeys("absolutepathtoimage\\testImage.jpg");
```

Check out the use of **not using** `click()` on button. It triggers the OS level modal dialog where selenium fails to automate.
I referred it from [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java) answer given by @talktokets

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files with Selenium you want to add the file path to the form (e.g., id: 'imageUpload') and then submit the form. You want to avoid triggering the system level dialog box since Selenium isn't able to handle this.

For Ruby, it would look like this:

```
file_upload = driver.find_element(id: 'imageUpload')
file_upload.send_keys('path/to/your/file')
file_upload.submit
```

You can see a full write-up that steps through this [here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/1-upload-a-file).

And if you're looking to run your tests on a remote node (e.g., with [Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) or on a third-party like [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/)) then you'll want to take a look at the [file_detector](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/DriverExtensions/UploadsFiles.html#file_detector%3D-instance_method) method.