# Upload a folder keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

a bit a newbie to robot framework and I need to upload a folder in the application I am testing.
I am aware of the keyword 'Choose File' providing the locator and the files location as the parameters.
I was wondering if there is anything similar to upload a folder?
I have tried with the 'Choose File' keyword with no success.

Many thanks

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java