# How to upload a file using Selenium IDE V2.9.0

Tags: selenium, ide

I have a scenario where in i need to upload a file using Selenium IDE version 2.9.0.
I tried using "Type" command with id of that element and path of that file as argument. But its not working. 
Is there any other way to upload a file using IDE? 
If there is no other way to upload using IDE, then what might be the issue?  Please suggest

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java I'm guessing the solution is similar for the IDE

Comment: Is it working for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getDriver().findElement(YourUploadButton).sendkeys(uploadFilepath);
```

Comment: How is this the right answer when the question is about Selenium IDE and not Selenium WD.