# How to automate file upload in chrome using selenium?

Tags: selenium

On an Ubuntu machine I try to automate file upload but I am unable to do so in Chrome using selenium. I tried with Robot class and normal send keys method.

**Please refer my code:**

StringSelection select = new StringSelection("/home/manojnn/Desktop/OrderDetails.xlsx");
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(select,null);

```
     System.out.println("selection" +select);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Upload']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
     Thread.sleep(1000);

      // Press Enter
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    // Release Enter
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

      // Press CTRL+V
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

    // Release CTRL+V
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     Thread.sleep(1000);


     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Show us how you've tried and provide `HTML` for target input

Comment: I have updated the information..please help me asap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Upload files using Selenium webdriver in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to click on upload button and handle upload prompt, but just to send path to file to appropriate input field. Try following solution and let me know if it not works:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@type="file"]')).sendKeys("/home/manojnn/Desktop/OrderDetails.xlsx");
```

Comment: You don't need to handle OS native pop ups!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the external tool like AUTOIT and can use it with selenium for upload purpose. Try this link
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/upload-a-file-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoit

Answer (score -1):

for file upload you need to do directly pass file path on the uploadfile text field.
use beloe 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(uploadTextFiledElementId)).sendKeys("filepath");