# Upload a file using Selenium IDE 2.9.1

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Am not able to upload a file using IDE.

The application consists of a NEW FILE button, after clicking on it, it opens Windows Popup for the file in the local machine .Once the file is found in the local, it needs to be uploaded.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Comment: Indeed seems like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is manipulating the dialog window ?
You can always make use of other (free) automating tools. I recommend using AutoIt. It's free, very straight forward.