# how to upload file with relative path in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am working with selenium automation and I am not able to upload file with relative path please see the below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Theme']")).click();

File filepath=new File("\ntwinelogin.jpg");
WebElement fileobj = driver.findElement(By.name("toplogoupload"));
fileobj.sendKeys("\ntwinelogin.jpg");
String Filepath=filepath.getAbsolutePath();
Filepath.trim();
```

Comment: You should get the absolute path and join that with your file name and then pass it.

Comment: similer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` for your current project directory path.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\ntwinelogin.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function for relative path in Python:

Import

```
import sys, os
```

Use code as below :

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
screenshotpath = os.path.join(os.path.sep, ROOT_DIR,'YOURFOLDERNAME'+ os.sep)
print screenshotpath
```

make sure you create folder where .py file is present

**Java**

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : First store the file in one variable e.g.  `String path = "C:\\users\\home\\newhtml.html";`

Step 2 : Pass the variable to `sendkeys()` method

```
driver.findelement(By.xapth("")).sendkeys(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently required a platform-agnostic solution to this problem. Since we were using Maven, I implemented the following solution.

> Maven directory structure

```
src
 |
  - main
 |    |
 |     - java
 |         |
 |          - com
 |             |
 |              - example
 |                   |
 |                    - integration
 |                            |
 |                             - Test1.java
 |                            |
 |                             - Test2.java
 |                            ...
 |
  - resources
        |
         - File1.csv
        |
         - File2.csv
        ...
```

> Test

```
// Load a file on the classpath as a resource using the ClassLoader.
URL    url  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("File1.csv");

// Convert the URL into a URI.
URI    uri  = file.toURI();

// Load the file from the URI.
File   file = new File(uri);

// Get the absolute path to the file.
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

// Use the absolute path with Selenium.
input.sendKeys(path);
```