# Why is control of flow not reaching to the file according to file path I am providing

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

While automating the upload file feature in selenium using Java, the control is not going to the file according to the file path I have provided. Why is the control not reaching to the file properly?

My code

```
uploadWebElement.click(); 
(new Actions(DriverConfiguration.driver())).sendKeys(new CharSequence[]{filePath, Keys.ENTER}).perform();
```

Error

The problem is when I clicked for browse, it opens the desktop folder and the one where I saved the file, is not reaching through this.

Comment: because line 37 is wrong

Comment: Where u see line 37

Comment: where is line 37

Comment: Please provide ur code

Comment: uploadWebElement.click();
        (new Actions(DriverConfiguration.driver())).sendKeys(new CharSequence[]{filePath, Keys.ENTER}).perform();

Comment: the problem is when i clicked for broswe it open the desktop folder and the one where i saved the file , is not reaching through this .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

if upload popup is windows/OS one then selenium can't work, if the popup up is related to browser then sendkeys will work to upload the file.

Point is actions bit not working in present gecko if you are using firefox.

For handling windows popup, you can try Robot class in java or AutoIT tool etc..