# Element not available - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I have a problem with one element on the web page. When I want somehow to interact with it(click on it, sendKeys or something) and every time I'm getting an error [IDE view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScEMH.png). In the browser I can click on this button and I locate it right [browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNqGS.png). All other elements on this website are working well. My task is to upload a file. In this case i want to make this -> `filePathUploadButton.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\ASuvorkov\\Desktop\\testverlG_serenity.png")` .

Manually it would be so:

1. User clicks on this button
2. Then user selects file in [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BRR1.png)
3. And the user clicks on "open file" to upload a file

Do you have any suggestions or experience with it, because I didn't meet such kind of things yet?

PS even checking if `element.isEnabled()`, `element.isDisplayed()` causes this error and programm breaks up.

Code snippet(JAVA):

```
@FindBy(id = "fileupload") private WebElement filePathUploadButton;

public void downloadCoverPicture() {
    waitABit(LONG_WAIT);

    element(mediaTypeDropDownButton).waitUntilClickable();
    mediaTypeDropDownButton.click();
    element(mediaTypeDropDownList).waitUntilClickable();
    mediaTypeDropDownList.click();

    waitABit(LONG_WAIT);
    element(filePathUploadButton).waitUntilClickable();
    filePathUploadButton.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\ASuvorkov\\Desktop\\testverlG_serenity.png");

    waitABit(50000);
}
```

Error stacktrace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: The following error occurred: Timed out after 10 seconds. Element not available

at pages.NewBookAddPage.downloadCoverPicture(NewBookAddPage.java:71)
at steps.NewBookManagementSteps.downloadsCoverPicture(NewBookManagementSteps.java:52)
at tests.NewBookManagementTest.addsNewBook(NewBookManagementTest.java:43)
```

Comment: Can you share where you're initializing `filePathUploadButton`?

Comment: @AlejandroC. if I right understand you, it is a line 53. There is `filePathUploadButton` initialized

Comment: sharing images of code and error is not a good idea. please share your code snippet, and error stacktrace

Comment: @GaurangShah added a code snippet and error stacktrace

Comment: how about waiting until element is visible

Comment: @GaurangShah unfortunatly is does not working, getting the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use `selenium` to interact with open file dialog. We can use `robot class` or `autoit` for that uses.

Click the file upload button and use the below `robot class` file upload implementation code.

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("Absolute path of the file");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection,null);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.setAutoDelay(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try it on Tuesday and write you if it works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine for me. Also the problem was with the selector

 `@FindBy(id = "fileupload") private WebElement filePathUploadButton;`. I do not know why, but this particular selector didn't work. I have tried several possibilities and found that

 `@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(.,'Durchsuchen...')]") private WebElement filePathUploadButton;` don't throw any exception. Your `Robot` class works fine.