# Element is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to upload the image here. I am getting the error as mentioned below. Can anyone of you guys help me in it as it is very important.
The code is and the error is mentioned too

```
package kemgo_package;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.omg.SendingContext.RunTime;
//import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class kengo_class 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.out.println("Hello");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Password
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/nav/div/ul[2]/li[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userClearBtn")).click();  //Click Auction
    System.out.println("hello world-----2");

     WebElement UploadImg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/label/p[2]")); //Image upload
     UploadImg.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Desktop\\Buyer_Detail_View.png");  //Select image
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/label/p[2]")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Desktop\\test Images\\1..jpg");  //Clicks on Browse button
    // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Desktop\\AutoIt\\UploadFile.exe");


}
}
```

ERROR:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <p class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-upload"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Comment: Tried to do it. But still not working.

Comment: @RAHUL , Its not the text box , how can you use sendkeys to that?

Comment: The locator you are using is pointing to a `P` tag and they don't take input from `.sendKeys()`. You need to point to the `INPUT` of `type='file'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Comment: Did you just post your real password to a live site?

Comment: Nops..
It's staging server..!!

Answer (score 1):

File can be uploaded directly using the selenium `sendkeys` if its accept to enter the path , otherwise you have to go for java `Robot` class to upload the file, like below.

```
public void uploadFile(WebDriver driver, String path) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        // To click on file upload button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row_dv text-center ']//p[text()='Picture Upload']")).click();
        // path is the absolute path of the image ex:
        // image(C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Desktop\\Buyer_Detail_View.png)
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(path);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

If your element `<p> ... </p>` is inside the `<input></input>` use `<input>` path better. And better relative path than absolute. E.g. "//input[contains(@class, 'some_class')]"
It worked for my case. I used "//*[contains(@class, 'some_class')]" and changed in into "//input[contains(@class, 'some_class')]" and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the absolute you are using sometimes refers to an input field and sometimes to a button. An xpath annotation like you have is not best practise. Try using a relative xpath.

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/label/p[2]
```

Try replacing this with a relative xpath and your problem should be solved. If you paste the html code of the input field, I can help you out there.