# ImportError: No module named forms.form when using pyrobot library

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying the solution for this issue here: [Access and handle chrome extension popup using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841197/access-and-handle-chrome-extension-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)

I'm getting an error when trying to import `pyrobot` and could not find any solution as to why I'm seeing this import error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jungle.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pyrobot import Robot
ImportError: cannot import name Robot
Chads-MacBook-Pro:amazon chad$ python jungle.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jungle.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pyrobot import Robot
  File "/Users/chad/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrobot/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .browser import RoboBrowser
  File "/Users/chad/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrobot/browser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .forms.form import Form
ImportError: No module named forms.form
```

Comment: Hi chadlei, you probably need to download the `pyrobot` library. I'm not very proficient with `python` but I think you're looking to do something like `pip install pyrobot` from the terminal or command line. If you run into trouble you could research _importing python libraries_.

Comment: hi, sorry I should have mentioned I ran pip install pyrobot but still ran into this issue for some reason. not sure which library I should be important since everything should be there

Comment: You might want to check out [this question about issues importing after pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32680081/1183506)

Comment: thanks, i tried using python -m pip install <library-name> instead but still had issues with .forms.form. its a library that pyrobot uses so im not sure why

Comment: Hi, Now I'm facing the same problem. I already install it using pip install pyrobot.
Could you answer how you solved it?
Thanks