# How to select a file from file dialog in selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a form, where `<input type="file">` is invisible but there is  a visible "Browse" button. I can't find element of file and update its value via sendKeys("filename").

I can use selenium to click "Browse" button and it will open a file dialog. How can I select a file in this open file dialog and close current dialog window?

Python 3.6
Selenium 3.0
Firefox webdriver
Mac OS.

Comment: using `sendkeys` also you can upload file https://stackoverflow.com/a/56168803/4513879 or using `robot` and `action class` you can upload file

Answer (score -1):

Once you have opened the dialog box use can use the following code to browse your file by pasting its location:

```
public static void copy(String text)
    {
     String myString = "file location";
     StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
     Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
     clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }

public static void paste() throws AWTException
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
```

Comment: That is not a python solution.