# Can not enter file path in File upload window

Tags: selenium, awtrobot

When I run this code, **file upload** window opens up but the selenium script hangs forever and could not enter **file path** in file upload window.

Please help.

```
public class ImageUpload {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    Robot robot = new Robot(); 
    driver.get("http://bg-dev.eweblife.com/prm/bgbtw/rsvp-signup/apply?record=826");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Upload new Photo")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("drop-area_field_12059")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //driver.switchTo().activeElement();
     StringSelection strSel = new StringSelection("C:/photo1.jpg");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(strSel, null);

    //Create an object for robot class

    //Control key in the keyboard
    //Ctrl+V 

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 


    Thread.sleep(3000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

   }
}
```

Comment: Go through this link ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56168803/4513879
May be this help you!!

Comment: I run your code in my m/c and its working file in this gives proper file path and after upload file it ask for crop and save option..

Comment: Do you have attribute called `file input type file` anywhere in the HTML.

Comment: I think path is wrong `C:/photo1.jpg` instead of '/' there should be show '\' .. May be this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats