# How to upload a picture in python selennium with a complicated HTML situation

Tags: python, selenium

I'm setting up a automatisation of a upload process of a website and I am struggeling right now with uploading a picture.

Normally you would use

```py
uploadBtn.send_keys(Path)
```

, but the image would just not upload. I have also been trying to implement some Javascript, so I added an attribute "type=file"

My Python code:

```py
uploadInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,\"Browse\")]")#
jsSetAttributeFileInput = "arguments[0].setAttribute(\"type\",\"file\")"
driver.execute_script(jsSetAttributeFileInput, uploadInput)
uploadInput.send_keys(design["DesignPath"])
```

The HTML of the Website:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> Browse </a>
```

I expect the result to upload my picture, but it just does not upload it. I don't get any errors, but it's just not uploading. I think it has something to do with the HTML, because it is an 'a'-tag instead of an 'input'-tag

Comment: You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56168803/4513879 ... you can upload a picture using 'Robot Class' also.

Comment: Do you see `<input type="file">` element in the upload node?

Comment: @supputuri No there is not.

Comment: So what I did, I implemented a script of autoit, now its working!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uploadInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,\"Browse\")]")
uploadInput.send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

and find your submit button and click it.

Where `os.getcwd()` returns the current working directory. `image.png` is located right next to the running script in the same directory

Comment: well, there is no submit button. thats the thing. The path also shouldnt be a problem

Comment: @SamsSkills have you tried my solution without submit button.

Comment: Now I tried it, but that didn't help. Still not uploading, I think it is because of the javascript, do you have a solution or workaround for that?