# selenium AutoIt Keyboard Types Incorrectly

Tags: c#, selenium, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'm Using **AutoIt** While Uploading Selenium Files.

But While Uploading, It Enters the File Path Wrong.

[image]

```
autoIt = new AutoItX3();

autoIt.WinActivate("Farklı Kaydet");
Thread.Sleep(1000);

autoIt.Send(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"video" + @"\" + textBox7.Text + "", 787000);
                autoIt.Send("{ENTER}");
```

How can I make the keyboard type slower and smoother?

787000
I Added But It Still Runs Fast and looking for wrong file path.

How do I solve this with **c#**
Tiktoka. I'm Trying to Upload Video

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not use autoIt for a file upload unless absolutely necessary. Hopefully you can just do it through the input element on the page. See here if you are not sure how to do it. [How to handle Windows file upload in .Net core using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551055/how-to-handle-windows-file-upload-in-net-core-using-selenium/61566075#61566075)

As for your question, type the characters individually. You can also create an additional try/catch so that if the typed value does not equal the displayed value, you can delete it and do it again.

```
        public static void TypeCharIndividually(IWebElement element, string expectedValue)
    {
        if (expectedValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (expectedValue == "n/a") { expectedValue = ""; }
        Driver.WaitForElementDisplayed(element);
        Driver.WaitForElementEnabled(element);
        element.Click();
        element.Clear();
        foreach (char c in expectedValue)
        {
            element.SendKeys(c.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Driver.WaitForSpinnerNoLongerDisplayed();
        }
        element.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
        string receivedValue = element.GetAttribute("value");
        if (receivedValue != expectedValue)
        {
            throw new Exception("Typed element not as expected");
        }
```