# How can i upload some file from local machine?

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using selenium with java script and i can't upload files from local machine. I tried using 'upload.sendKeys(direction from file)', but does not work. When i clicking on the upload button and open a window to select a file from local machine i don't know how i can select a file.

```
await findByCss(driver, selectContent).click();

await delay();

var upload = findByCss(driver, selectContent);

upload.sendKeys("C:/trabajo/Pineapple-lab/para docola/Actualidad_356226259_107392298_1024x576.jpg"); 

await delay();
```

Comment: IIRC selenium doesn't support file uploads.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java

Comment: @Jorjon You recall incorrectly. Selenium WebDriver has supported file uploads for years via the `sendKeys` method, by sending the path and file name to the `<input type='file'>` element on the page.

Comment: @JimEvans Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly one should not issue a click and send the path directly (because the click will open a dialog that Selenium cannot interact with).
Of course you also need some way of handling the file, either a form to send it or a `change` handler on the input itself.