# How to upload file using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question,
I want to upload a file in a popup window that is open in my web application.

1. I can not inspect the element of the popup window, window that is opened (F12 not response in this window)
2. I try this solutions that not worked

   ```
   WebDriver deiver2 = getWebDriver();
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            Alert alert = deiver2.switchTo().alert();
            alert.sendKeys("yyyyy");
   ```

the second attemp is:

```
WebDriver deiver2 = getWebDriver();
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        deiver2.switchTo()
                .activeElement()
        .sendKeys(
                "yyyyy");
        System.out.println("END");
```

In the first attempt it says that no alert exists.
In the second attempt it passed but I do not see it feel value in the text field (still blank),
How I can upload a file in selenium via popup. (and how to inspect the path field to locate the element in the new popup?)

this is the popup screen.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java

Answer (score 0):

this is what solved it

```
deiver2.switchTo()
                .activeElement();
        System.out.println("Window title: "+ deiver2.getTitle());

        deiver2.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))
        .sendKeys(
                "X:\\AutomationFiles\\yyyyy.pdf");
```