# File Upload Using Selenium WebDriver and Java on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I have a web application which I am attempting to automate using Java, TestNG, and Selenium WebDriver. The application navigates through several stages and then the user needs to upload a document.

I have tried the suggestions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610256/file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java)

and have been unable to get it to work. I do not believe that `browseBtn.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());` is going to work in this case as I am trying to do this on a Mac and there is no cursor for the Browse button.

Below is my code thus far, just wondering if anyone has been able to successfully do this and how to do it myself (Screenshots of what I am trying to do are below):

```
    private void documents_UploadDocuments(String driverName) throws SQLException, InterruptedException
{
    /*
     * Upload documents to a request
     */
            Login.login_Requester(driverName);
            WebDriver driver = Login.driver;

            //Click My Requests Tab
            WebElement myRequestTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/ul/li[2]/a"));
            myRequestTab.click();

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //Click Create a New Request
            WebElement createRequestBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
            createRequestBtn.click();

            WebElement officialNameTB = driver.findElement(By.id("new-official-name"));
            WebElement createRqtBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("continue"));
            WebElement researchDataAccess = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/select/optgroup/option"));

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            officialNameTB.sendKeys("TEST_UploadDocuments");
            researchDataAccess.click();
            createRqtBtn.click();

            Thread.sleep(2500);


            //Enter an IRB Number
            WebElement irbNumberTB = driver.findElement(By.id("irbNumber"));
            irbNumberTB.click();
            irbNumberTB.sendKeys("This is an IRB #");

            //Enter an IRB Expiration Date
            WebElement irbExpCP = driver.findElement(By.id("irbExpDate"));
            irbExpCP.click();
            LocalDate irbDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(5);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String irbDate2 = formatter.print(irbDate);
            irbExpCP.sendKeys(irbDate2);

            //Enter a Start Date
            WebElement startDateCP = driver.findElement(By.id("startDate"));
            startDateCP.click();
            LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
            String startDate2 = formatter.print(startDate);
            startDateCP.sendKeys(startDate2);

            //Enter an End Date
            WebElement endDateCP = driver.findElement(By.id("endDate"));
            endDateCP.click();
            LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(10);
            String endDate2 = formatter.print(endDate);
            endDateCP.sendKeys(endDate2);

            //Click Next Button
            WebElement nextBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/button"));
            nextBtn.click();

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //Click Find Participant button
            WebElement findPartBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("findPeopleButton"));
            findPartBtn.click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //Search for a participant
            WebElement nameField = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
            nameField.click();
            nameField.clear();
            String [] namesArray = {"Salisbury, Curtis J. (FVFT)", "Hanson, Shannon H. (FVFT)", "Dinerstein, Jared A. (FVFT)", "Dinerstein, Sabra A. (FVFT)", "Ford, Lee J. (FVFT)"};
            String names = PickRand.get(namesArray);
            nameField.sendKeys(names);

            //Find Now Button
            WebElement findBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("findNow"));
            findBtn.click();

            //Choose the Participant
            WebElement fullName = driver.findElement(By.id("fullName"));
            fullName.click();

            //Choose a location
            String location = PickRand.get(locations.getLocationArray());
            WebElement locationChooser = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/label/div/a/div/b"));
            locationChooser.click();
            WebElement locationSrch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/label/div/div/div/input"));
            locationSrch.clear();
            locationSrch.sendKeys(location);
            locationSrch.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            WebElement addBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/button"));
            addBtn.click();
            Thread.sleep(500);

            nextBtn.click();
            Thread.sleep(500);

            //Click RealSSN Identifier
            WebElement realSSNIdentifier = driver.findElement(By.id("realSSNIdentifier"));
            realSSNIdentifier.click();

            //Click CDW Production Domains Data Source
            WebElement cdwProdDomainsCheck = driver.findElement(By.id("1022"));
            cdwProdDomainsCheck.click();

            //Click the HIPAA questions
            WebElement hipaaConsentYesRdio = driver.findElement(By.id("HIPAAAuthorization1"));
            WebElement hipaaWaiverYesRdio = driver.findElement(By.id("HIPAAWaiver1"));
            hipaaConsentYesRdio.click();
            hipaaWaiverYesRdio.click();

            //Click Next Button
            nextBtn.click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);


            //Upload Documents
            WebElement uploadDoc1 = driver.findElement(By.id("uploadDocumentLink"));
            uploadDoc1.click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement browseBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('fileField')"));
            File file = null;
            try
            {
                file = new File(Documents_UploadDocuments.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf").toURI());
            }
            catch(URISyntaxException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            browseBtn.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());

}
```

The upload link opens this screen: 
[image: Choose File Modal]

When I click on the Browse button in that modal it opens this screen:
[image: File Upload Screen]

So I attempted to use the `Robot` class as suggested and it is not actually choosing the file. I need it to choose the file, and then go back to the `Upload a Document` screen so I can click the `Upload` button to finish the process. When I run the full test, it just stays on the Mac screen for the File Upload. What am I doing wrong?

Below is what I have for using the `Robot` class:

```
//Upload Documents
            WebElement uploadDoc1 = driver.findElement(By.id("uploadDocumentLink"));
            uploadDoc1.click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement browseBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('fileField')"));
            browseBtn.click();
            Robot r = new Robot();
            /*
             * use the Robot class to type out the path of the document
             * "/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf"
             */
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH); 
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            WebElement uploadBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
            uploadBtn.click();
```

The `Login.driver` implementation is below:

```
public class Login 
{
static Browser browser = new Browser();
HighlightElement highlight = new HighlightElement();
static WebDriver driver;
static String user = "UserName";
static String pwd = "password";
static int userID;

/*
 * Connection Strings:
 * testDB = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:Connection String"
 * devDB = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:Connection String"
 */

public static void login_Page(String driverName)
{
    driver = browser.getDriver(driverName);

    //navigate to VINCI login page
    driver.get("http://URL/vinci_dart_client/dart9/index.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
public static void login_Requester(String driverName) throws InterruptedException, SQLException
{
    //Change user role to requester
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:Connection String");
    PreparedStatement ps1, ps2, ps3;
    ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select id from hib.person where name = ?");
    ps2 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.personrole where personid = ?");
    ps3 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.persongroup where personid = ?");

    ps1.setString(1, user);

    ResultSet rs = ps1.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        userID = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    rs.close();
    ps1.close();

    ps2.setInt(1, userID);
    ps3.setInt(1, userID);

    ps2.execute();
    ps3.execute();

    driver = browser.getDriver(driverName);

    //navigate to VINCI login page
    driver.get("http://URL");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    //Enter User Name
    WebElement userNameField = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    userNameField.clear();
    userNameField.sendKeys(user);

    //Enter Password
    WebElement pwdField = driver.findElement(By.id("pword"));
    pwdField.clear();
    pwdField.sendKeys(pwd);

    //Click Login Button
    WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/form/div[4]/div/input"));
    loginBtn.click();

}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What browser are you using?  Can I see the HTML of the `officialNameTB` element?

Comment: @MrTi The `officialNameTB` element has nothing to do with the document upload. That part is working. I am using Firefox, and the error I am getting is a null pointer exception on the `file = new File(Documents_UploadDocuments.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf").toURI());` line.

Comment: Ah.  I saw sendKeys and I thought that was where you uploaded it.    This has nothing to do with Selenium then.  I believe your problem lies with the fact that the path is wrong.  I'm not sure why, but its definitely not Selenium that's causing that error.

Comment: The file path is correct, not really sure where to go to get this to work.

Comment: Well, can you run this test: `if (Documents_UploadDocuments.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf")==null) System.out.println("Null check");`

Comment: I'm also not sure if you need to start it with the Drive name.  Put a `C:/` in front?

Comment: I am running this on a mac, so that is the correct path.

Comment: The null check you suggested passes.

Comment: The `sendKeys()` should work. Is the `<input type="file" multiple>` input with the `multiple` attribute by any chance? WebDriver doesn't support it. Can you show us your html code around the input? If everything fails, try the `Robot` class. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14628195/1273080

Comment: @Slanec I am unsure what `<input type="file" multiple>` means, does that mean that it can accept different types of formats? For instance .doc, .docx, and .pdf. If that is the case, then yes it does support multiple formats. Will the `Robot` class work in that case?

Comment: @DarthOpto Just show us the HTML code. And no, it means that it can simultaneously accept multiple files. It's a new HTML5 feature. And yes, the Robot solution should work, even though it's a little hacky.

Comment: @Slanec `<input type="file" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" name="files[]" id="fileField">` Trying Robot.

Comment: `Robot` class is not working either. It never actually goes to the file.

Comment: Can you also add to the question what is your WebDriver implementation (Login.driver).

Comment: Does Mac not let you navigate and select files with finder using the keyboard? Can't you just automate keys?

Comment: @eis added the `Login.driver` implementation

Comment: @Okuma.Scott it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Depending if you want to test the various Browsers or only the backend functionality, you could switch to HtmlUnit and populate the form directly instead of trying to handle the file open dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not believe that browseBtn.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath()); is going
>   to work in this case as I am trying to do this on a Mac and there is no cursor
>   for the Browse button.

There isn't a cursor in any platform for file input. That shouldn't keep you from using it. However, I'd suggest changing this:

```
WebElement browseBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('fileField')"));
```

To this

```
WebElement browseBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("fileField"));
```

to see if that fixes the issue.

---

Update: You added that

> I am still getting a null pointer exception at file = new
>   File(Documents_UploadDocuments.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Users/vhaisl‌​salisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf").toURI());

This means that **next problem is with loading from path `/Users/vhaisl‌​salisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf`**. That is not related in Selenium usage at all, and you need to fix the path/file/file permissions before continuing with the troubleshooting.

Try to change this

```
file = new File(Documents_UploadDocuments.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf").toURI());
```

to this

```
file = new File("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf");
```

Comment: Funnily enough, [there is an `id()` function in XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id), so the code is okay. Anyway, searching `By.id()` should be preferred.

Comment: Hm. So it seems. However, as that's only thing I can think of that would be wrong, I'd still confirm it or test it with just By.id(). There are [differences and limitations in WebDriver xpath support](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/XpathInWebDriver), and this might be one of them.

Comment: @eis when I try your suggestion I am still getting a `null pointer exception` at `file = new File(Documents_UploadDocuments.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/VINCI_Test_documents/Test_ResReqMemo.pdf").toURI());`

Comment: @DarthOpto that's a different problem. if you get a null pointer exception there, it means loading of your resource from that path failed. Fix that first (by correcting the path, path cases, permissions of the file/path or similar). That's not related to webdriver in any way.

Comment: @eis I changed the permissions on the directory that the file is in, and the path is correct. I am in the process now of changing the permissions for the entire path.

Comment: @DarthOpto that might not be the issue. Try putting the path directly to new File(). I added an example.

Comment: My computer crashed the other day. I will try your suggestion as soon as I get it back.

Comment: I got my computer back and am working on this right now. Will let you know how this worked out.

Comment: Taking out that bit worked. Thank you all so much for your help. I am sorry that it took so long to get back to this. My hard drive on my computer went tits up and needed replaced, since it is a government computer it took forever. +1 Internets for @eis

Answer (score 0):

The guide [here](http://learn-automation.com/upload-file-in-selenium-in-mac/) work for me. My code

```
public static void uploadMediaByRobot(String fileName) {
    //File Need to be imported
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/media/" + fileName);
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(file.getAbsolutePath());
    //Copy to clipboard
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Cmd + Tab is needed since it launches a Java app and the browser looses focus
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.delay(500);

    //Open Goto window
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);

    //Paste the clipboard value
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

    //Press Enter key to close the Goto window and Upload window
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.delay(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

Btw, if you meet the error

`ERROR : This is NOT allowed. Please call TIS/TSM in main thread!!!`

You can solve with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54965052/3894987)

Hope this help!