# Java.awt.Robot keyPress and keyRelease not working at all

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

Whenever I try using the java.awt.Robot keyPress or keyRelease, it gives me the error message `pid(25807)/euid(501) is calling TIS/TSM in non-main thread environment, ERROR : This is NOT allowed. Please call TIS/TSM in main thread!!!`. No matter how simple I make the code, it keeps giving this error message. This is my code:

```
package com;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class JavaRobotExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
    
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    }
}
```

This is the textbook example I found, yet it still gives that error message. I've been searching for so long trying to figure out what is wrong. I use MacOS Mojave 10.14.2 on a MacBook Pro, and I have given Eclipse (what I use to compile the code) privacy access. Here is a screenshot of everything I use for this:
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXz9d.png)

Does anyone else have this issue? I should also note that the error message is sent multiple times, even though it only presses the key once.

Comment: That code works on Windows. Try doing the actions on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps below,

1. Settings -> Security & Privacy
2. Scroll down to "Accessibility"
3. Click the lock button at the bottom and unlock the security and
   privacy preferences
4. Click on '+' icon and your program (Eclipse IDE in my case) and try
   running again

The Eclipse IDE still shows "This is NOT allowed. Please call TIS/TSM in main thread!!!" but both Keyboard and Mouse events work.