# Selenium/Java - Uploading a file with PLUpload

Tags: java, testing, selenium, plupload, uploading

I'm working for a company and their site has to ability to upload a CV on their careers site.

The problem I'm having is that they haven't used the standard HTML5 file uploading system. They are using a JavaScript plugin called [PLUpload](http://www.plupload.com/). At the moment, you click on the Upload File anchor element and the OS dialog box appears for you to select a file. There is no Input element with the type of file on the page for me to use `sendKeys()`.

I need to be able to upload a file to the form through Selenium to automate a test that applies for each job one after the other.

If anyone has any suggestions, they'd be greatly appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know to do that is java robot. Please view this topic for more information-[How to upload a file in Selenium with no text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592853/how-to-upload-a-file-in-selenium-with-no-text-box)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no `input` of `file` type?
Check again. I was also thinking that there is no such input, because I checked only `Add Files` button that didn't really have input. Try searching for an element using the simple CSS selector:

```
input[type=file]
```

Also note that the input won't be visible, so `Displayed` will be `false` in Selenium.